# forming an IP out of two variables

Tags: bash, shell

I apologize beforehand if the question is out of place.
I'm working on a script that greps the first three octets of an IP address and sends it to a variable.
Next I want to use that variable and set a range in a for loop but it's not working.

This is my code;

```
device_ip=$(ip addr show eth1 | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.')

for i in {191..200};
do
printf device_ip | ping -c 1 "$device_ip""$i"
done
```

It does everything except for combining the two variables to ping.
Output;

sh myscript.sh

```
ping: unknown host x.x.x.
x.x.x.{191..200}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?
Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm under the impression that your `grep` will leave `device_ip` with two lines, since it will match the broadcast address as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
device_ip="$(ip -o -4 a sh eth1|grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.'|head -1)" # make sure you get only the first IP, in case eth1 returns more than 1

for i in {191..200}
do
echo pinging IP: ${device_ip}${i}
ping -c1 ${device_ip}${i}
done
```

Comment: Hi Ron, many thanks for the super quick answer. Sadly the result is much the same, ping: unknown host x.x.x.{191..200}

Comment: Are you using bash? Also can you can try `$(seq 191 200)` instead of `{191..200}`. What I provided as an answer is tested and works in bash... please check it carefully, or directly copy/paste the answer..

Comment: I come back to thank Ron. got it working using this method. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
for ip in $device_ip.{191..200}; do ping -c 1 $ip; done
```

*Is it possible you aren't using `bash`?*
Check your `#!` shebang line. If your very first line's very first two characters aren't `#!` then it's just a comment.

Also,

```
printf device_ip | ping -c 1 "$device_ip""$i"
```

Is not going to do what you expect. It's going to print the string "device_ip" onto the STDIN of `ping`, which isn't coing to read it. Take the `printf` statement out entirely, it serves no purpose and confuses the code.

Also, while this will work, it's a little visually noisy for no reason. `"$device_ip""$i"` generates the same output at `"$device_ip$i"`, which is easier to read. Perhaps even better, `"${device_ip}${i}"`. That's all just a style preference, though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution:

```sh
device_ip=($(ip -o address show eth0 | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}'))

for address in ${device_ip[0]}{191..200}; do
    ping -c 1 $address
done
```

And here is an alternative using Bash match operator:

```sh
if [[ $(ip -o address show eth0) =~ ([0-9]{1,3}\.){3} ]]; then
    for address in ${BASH_REMATCH}{191..200}; do
        ping -c 1 $address
    done
fi
```